# Use of $E( X(X-1) )$ to calculate variance of random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, poisson-distribution, variance

In an exercise I had to calculate the variance of the Poisson-distribution.
In the solution, $E( X(X-1) )$ was used, which for me fell out of thin air:

[image: Solution]

I can see how this works out, but I'd like to know some context.

Is this a common technique?
Does it have a name?
Are there similar "tricks" to calculate the variance?

Comment: Hi Moritz. It does not have a specific name but it is useful because solving for $E(X(X-1))$ is much simpler than solving for $E(X^2)$. The same happens with the geometric distribution. I remember another very useful trick when computing moments of continuous random variables, which is to multiply and divide by some constants so that you get a Gamma distribucion inside the integral. Maybe the most important one is to use the moment generating function whenever it is possible. It simplifies things a lot

Comment: [Factorial moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_moment) are sometimes easier to find than finding some higher order moment directly.

Comment: @StubbornAtom yeah I guess that was the term I was looking for.